# SQL developer count(*) with 0

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create view PHOTO (TITRE_DOC, NB_PERSONNE,AUTEUR_DOC, DATE_PUBLICATION_DOC) as 
    select D.TITRE_DOC, COUNT(*),D.AUTEUR_DOC, D.DATE_PUBLICATION_DOC
    from DOCUMENTS D, DOCUMENT_ACTEURS DA
    where D.NO_DOC = DA.NO_DOC and D.TYPE_DOC = 'Photo'
    group by D.TITRE_DOC, D.AUTEUR_DOC, D.DATE_PUBLICATION_DOC;
```

How do I change that if I want to have the one with the count of 0?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` or `NOT EXISTS`

Answer (score 3):

You need to learn to use explicit join syntax.  Just say "no" to commas in the `from` clause:

```
create view PHOTO(TITRE_DOC, NB_PERSONNE,AUTEUR_DOC, DATE_PUBLICATION_DOC) as 
    select D.TITRE_DOC, COUNT(da.NO_DOC), D.AUTEUR_DOC, D.DATE_PUBLICATION_DOC
    from DOCUMENTS D left outer join
         DOCUMENT_ACTEURS DA
         on D.NO_DOC = DA.NO_DOC
    where D.TYPE_DOC = 'Photo'
    group by D.TITRE_DOC, D.AUTEUR_DOC, D.DATE_PUBLICATION_DOC;
```